# How to add choices for a BASH trashbin script?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am struggling with some commands for a scripting practice, I am supposed to make a "trash" directory in my home directory that utilizes a script. The script needs to present a menu of choices to either **delete a file**, **empty the trash bin** or **exit**. If I need to delete a file it asks for the file name, if i select empty trash bin it must empty the directory but not remove the directory itself and how do I implement a "are you sure" feature? 
This is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3='Select your choice: '
options=("Delete File?" "Empty Trashbin?" "Exit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Delete File?")
            echo "Are you sure you want to delete?"
            ;;
        "Empty Trashbin?")
            echo "Are you sure you want to empty trashbin?"
            ;;
        "Exit")
            break
            ;;
```

Comment: Just to clarify more, here are the guidelines for the script, A) Present you with an menu with choices “Delete File?”, “Empty Trashbin?” & “Exit”
B) If you select delete a file it asks for the file name to delete
C) If you select empty the trashbin it should empty the Trashbin but not remove the directory itself.
D) For either B or C it should always ask you to confirm the action before it does it.
If you say no it does nothing and returns to the menu.
If you say yes it moves the file to the Trashbin directory or empties the Trashbin.

Comment: for B and C you prompt with another question, read/select the user's input, and process accordingly; this can be done within the individual `case` sections (you can even have nested `case` statements); the current code is also missing the endings for the `do` and `case` statements (namely `esac` and `done`)

Comment: Please close off your `case` and `do` with the appropriate `esac` and `done`. Readers want code they can copy/paste into their local environment. Good luck.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `dialog` as pointed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/how-can-i-create-a-select-menu-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 1):

I added some parts to your script, I hope it helps

```
#!/bin/bash
FILEPATH="$1"
BINDIR="/tmp/trashbin"

PS3='Select your choice: '
options=("Delete File?" "Empty Trashbin?" "Exit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Delete File?")
                [ -z "$FILEPATH" ] && { echo "Please provide a file as argument";break; }
                echo "Are you sure you want to delete \"$FILEPATH\"?"
                read -r ANSWER
                [ "$ANSWER" == "y" ] || [ "$ANSWER" == "Y" ] && {
                        rm -rf "$FILEPATH"
                }
                break
            ;;
        "Empty Trashbin?")
                echo "Are you sure you want to empty trashbin?"
                read -r ANSWER
                [ "$ANSWER" == "y" ] || [ "$ANSWER" == "Y" ] && {
                        rm -rf "${BINDIR:?}/"*                     
                }
                break
            ;;
        "Exit")
            break
            ;;
esac
done
exit 0
```